# How to get the current position of a shape in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a circle with these two methods in qt:

```
void MyGLWidget::drawCircle() {
int n = vertices.count();
qglColor(Qt::white);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    glVertex2f(vertices[i].first, vertices[i].second);
    }
glEnd();
}



void MyGLWidget::calculateVetices()
{
    double a = 3.14 / 90;
    vertices.append(QPair<double, double> (0,0));
    for(int i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
        vertices.append(QPair<double, double> (cos(i * a) * radius, sin(i * a) * radius));
    }
}
```

Now I want to get the current position of this circle. How can I do that?

Comment: Does it inherit from `QGraphicsEllipseItem`? If yes, you can retrieve position relative to the scene by calling `getSceneRect()` and then finding it's centre. Anyway, the `QGraphicsEllipseItem` should be enough for whatever you're doing in the `QGraphicsView`.

Comment: No, it doesn't. But after inheriting, what does `getSceneRect()` do exactly? I just want to be sure if I've got your explanation or not, I should find the center of the circle?

Comment: it returns upper left corner of the rectangle in which circle fits (from geometry it is a square with sides 2R). So you'll have to calculate the center using simple math yourself.